Drive failures on Lenovo ThinkSystem SR590 and why its a "Withdrawn Product"?
our small data center faces 1 or 2 drive (SSD, SATA & SAS) failures every year in RAID-1 and RAID-5 setup on Lenovo ThinkSystem SR590 servers.
Today while I was searching the internet about the issue, I saw "Withdrawn Product" written on the official page of Lenovo.
https://lenovopress.lenovo.com/lp1048-thinksystem-sr590-server-xeon-sp-gen2
What I am trying to understand is:
a. Is hard drive failure a common problem with this specific brand or model?
b. What does "Withdrawn Product" exactly mean in the computer world?
c. Why was this specific product withdrawn from the market? (Found no information on the internet)
Thanks

Seems to be a standard procedure when they stop selling a particular model. https://www.lenovo.com/content/dam/lenovo/dcg/global/en/products/networking/Lenovo-Networking-Product-Withdrawal-Notice.pdf / https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/servers/thinksystem/sr590/7x99/solutions/ht504708-lenovo-end-of-service-dates-for-serversstoragenetworking-products

Hard drive attrition rate is linked to the manufacturer, model, and batch of the hard drives. Lenovo likely selected the wrong/cheapest drives that they then relabeled. There is zero information about the offending drives that you purchased so the discussion isn't of much use. https://www.backblaze.com/blog/backblaze-drive-stats-for-q2-2024/
